# Why throws keyword cannot handle the exception thrown in field declaration

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throws

In the code below, `Thread.sleep(3000);` written inside the anonymous class instantiation can be handled only using a try-catch block. Why doesn't the `throws InterruptedException` clause allow the exception to propagate?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // below line explicitly need to be handled using try-catch. throws keyword does not work here
            Thread.sleep(3000);         
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with field declaration. Try  putting the `Runnable task = ...` inside a method: you will get exactly the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `run()` method lacks a `throws InterruptedException` clause. It doesn't matter that `main()` has one, nor that `run()` is defined in an class defined inside of `main()`. They're two different methods.

Adding one to `run()` isn't possible, though, because `Runnable` doesn't allow `run()` to have a `throws` clause. Therefore, the only solution is to wrap the `sleep` with a try/catch block.

Comment: Same answer. The nesting doesn't matter.

Comment: So, that means inside the anonymous inner class, an exception can be handled only using the try-catch block.

Comment: @SKumar no: a *checked* exception must always be handled, either with try/catch or with a `throws` declaration on the method. You can't add a `throws` declaration to a method that is not covariant with any of the `throws` declaration of that it is overriding. `Runnable.run()` implicitly `throws RuntimeException, Error`; `InterruptedException` is covariant with neither, so you can't add `throws InterruptedException`. Therefore, you have to use try/catch. If your anonymous class were e.g. `Callable`, you could use `throws`, because `Callable.call()` throws `Exception`.